# jQuery Drag and Drop between specific lists only

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a little problem which I am trying to solve, being reasonably new to javascript isn't helping me (i'm from a c# background and always told myself I would learn javascript properly one day!) and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

I have 5 different lists, list A,B,C,D and a Bucket List.  The idea is that you can drag list items from List A, B, C or D into the Bucket, but anything in the bucket can only go to 1 list (other than itself).  Essentially an item can only be in it's correctly labeled list, or the bucket, nothing else.

So, i've got my lists created, and I am using the data tag to keep track of which item is supposed to be in which list (data-pos="A") etc.

I can get the items to go from the lettered lists INTO the bucket, but then when i try and drag them back out, the alert tells me it is the correct data, but automatically goes back to the bucket list and doesn't sit in the list it is dragged to.

I was hoping to do something similar to my `connectWith: "#" + position + "List ul, #bucketList ul"` on the sort-able list (which I assume is where the problem lies?) but i'm not having any luck accessing the data attributes at this point.  Perhaps this isn't the right way of going about this?

I've got the following so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/graham_m84/vk7jeba2/

It's probably super simple for a javascript wizz but i've been reading and racking my brains for ages now and decided to ask for help with my tail between my legs :)

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be a very happy man.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, among other help documentation.  The jsfiddle is good; we should also have a bulleted list of repro steps without equivocation.

I'd love to follow this with a solution, but I'm no longer the JS programmer I used to be.

Comment: Your one tracing statement is also good; try putting in a couple of others to trace your logic in making the transfer from the Bucket to the proper list.

Comment: Thanks for the reading materials and guidance @Prune :)